# Sorting by DateTime in Slick

Tags: scala, slick

I'm currently going through a rough point in Slick. I'm trying to sort the query of a table with a timestamp:

```
TableName.filter(tableAttribute === 1).sortBy(_.tableTimestamp)
```

The timestamp is of type `joda.DateTime` within slick. When I try to sort, I'm getting the following error:

`No implicit view available from dao.Tables.profile.api.Rep[org.joda.time.DateTime] => slick.lifted.Ordered.`

I'm assuming that this isn't built into Slick. Is there a quick and clean way to add an implicit view and solve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be looking for an implicit conversion using [Ordering.fromLessThan](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/math/Ordering$.html#fromLessThan[T](cmp:(T,T)=%3EBoolean):scala.math.Ordering[T]) like below:

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime

implicit def datetimeOrdering: Ordering[DateTime] = Ordering.fromLessThan(_ isBefore _)
```

In case you want to reverse the ordering, simply replace `isBefore` with `isAfter`.